# Starting with ring theory

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Can anyone suggest a book on rings explaining concepts using visual diagrams, similar to the one visual group theory book by **Nathan Carter** for groups.The problem with me is that after reading that book I am visualizing everything in terms of Cayley's diagram,cycle graphs etc. and now I'm feeling if I'll use a standard book i'll be missing some great things.
I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: Nathan Carter, maybe? Cartan is someone else...

Comment: thank for pointing mistake .It's Nathan Carter.

Answer (score 1):

Good books depend on choice and can vary from person to person. Here are a few of my favorites:

1. Contemporary abstract algebra by J A Gallian can be a good book to start with since it  has plenty of exercises.
2. Topics in Algebra by I N Herstein: A classic in its own way. Very well written and amazing exercises.
3. A book of Abstract Algebra by Charles C pinter: It explains things beautifully and can be a good place to start with.

Comment: You didn't answer the question - books about rings that are visual.